# Which of Sacchetti’s stories are parodied in "The Ring and the Book"?

Tags: robert-browning, the-ring-and-the-book, franco-sacchetti

In book V of Robert Browning’s [*The Ring and the Book*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Ring_and_the_Book) (1868), Count Guido Franceschini compares his plight to that of a character in a story by [Franco Sacchetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco_Sacchetti):

> Aha, Sacchetti again!—“Dame,”—quoth the Duke,
>   “What meaneth this epistle, counsel me,
>   I pick from out thy placket* and peruse,
>   Wherein my page averreth thou art white
>   And warm and wonderful ’twixt pap and pap?”
>   “Sir,” laughed the Lady, “’t is a counterfeit!
>   Thy page did never stroke but Dian’s breast,
>   The pretty hound I nurture for thy sake:
>   To lie were losel†,—by my fay‡, no more!”
>
> <sub>* a pocket in a skirt or dress † worthless ‡ faith</sub>

Hawlin and Burnett describe this passage as

> a parody of Sacchetti, not an actual quotation from his work.
>
> <sub>Stefan Hawlin and Tim Burnett, eds. (2001). [*The Poetical Works of Robert Browning: Volume VIII. The Ring and the Book, Books 5–8*, p. 61.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=krNwzIbd42EC&pg=RA3-PA61) Oxford: Clarendon.</sub>

Which of Sacchetti’s stories, and what elements of them, are being parodied here?